Reparametrization in the proof of the infinite cyclicity of $\pi_1(S^1,1)$.
Let $I = [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$, let $\alpha_{n}:I \to S^1$ be defined by $\alpha_n(s) = e^{2\pi i sn}$ and let $\omega:I \to S^1$ be defined by $\omega(s) = e^{2\pi i s}$.
Then in the proof of theorem 8.9 (J. Lee:s "Introduction to Topological Manifolds") it is claimed that $\alpha_{n}$ is a reparametrization of $\alpha_{n-1} \ast \omega$. So I believe I want to find a continuous map $\phi:I \to I$ such that \begin{align*} \begin{cases} \phi(0) = 0\\ \phi(1) = 1, \end{cases} \end{align*} and so that $$(\alpha_{n-1} \ast \omega)(\phi(s)) = \alpha_{n}(s).$$
Since we have
\begin{align*} (\alpha_{n-1} \ast \omega)(s) =  \begin{cases} e^{2\pi i (n-1)2s}, \qquad 0 \leqslant s \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\\ e^{2\pi  i (2s-1)}, \qquad \frac{1}{2} \leqslant s \leqslant 1, \end{cases} \end{align*} I believe I want $\phi(s) = \frac{sn}{2(n-1)}$ for $0 \leqslant s \leqslant \frac{1}{2}$, but I can't figure out how to define $\phi$ on $\frac{1}{2} \leqslant s \leqslant 1$ such that $\phi$ is continuous at $s = \frac{1}{2}$.
I'd be happy for suggestions.

Perhaps this answer of mine might help.

@BenSteffan Thanks! It is not immediately obvious to me how to apply what you wrote in my scenario (I am unsure exactly what the questioner is asking there, just from skimming the question).

Ah, I might have misread the question somewhat. Still, the idea applies: $\phi$ will be something piecewise affine, and to define an affine map there's only so many values of function you need to figure out. The rest is algebra. Drawing pictures for small $n$ might help :)

You have to map $[0,1- \frac 1 n]$ linearly onto $[0, \frac 1 2]$ and $[1- \frac 1 n, 1]$ linearly onto $[\frac 1 2, 1]$. Since $1- \frac 1 n = \frac{n-1}{n}$, this means
$$\phi(s) = \begin{cases} \frac{ns}{2(n-1)} & s \le \frac{n-1}{n} \\   \frac{ns}{2} - \frac{n-1}{2} +  \frac 1 2&   s \ge \frac{n-1}{n} \end{cases}$$
For $s \le \frac{n-1}{n}$ we get
$$(\alpha_{n-1} * \omega)(\phi(s)) = \alpha_{n-1}(2\phi(s)) = \alpha_{n-1}\left(2\frac{ns}{2(n-1)}\right) = e^{2\pi i (n-1)\frac{2ns}{2(n-1)}} = e^{2\pi i n s}$$
and for $s \ge \frac{n-1}{n}$
$$(\alpha_{n-1} * \omega)(\phi(s)) = \omega(2\phi(s) - 1) = \omega\left(2(\frac{ns}{2} - \frac{n-1}{2} +  \frac 1 2) -1\right) = \omega\left(ns - (n -1) \right) \\ = e^{2\pi i ns -2 \pi i(n -1)} = e^{2\pi i ns} .$$
Update.
What is the idea to define $\phi$?
$\alpha_n$ wraps $I$ exactly $n$-times around $S^1$ (with constant speed). That is, each subinterval $[\frac{i-1}{n}, \frac i n]$ with $i = 1,\ldots, n$ is wrapped once around $S^1$. Thus $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$ is wrapped $(n-1)$-times around $S^1$ and $[\frac{n-1}{n}, 1]$ is wrapped once around $S^1$.
$\alpha_{n-1} * \omega$ wraps $[0, \frac 1 2]$ exactly $(n-1)$-times around $S^1$ and $[ \frac 1 2, 1]$ once around $S^1$.
Thus both $\alpha_n$ and $\alpha_{n-1} * \omega$ wrap $I$
exactly $n$-times around $S^1$; the first with constant speed, the second with different speeds on $[0, \frac 1 2]$ and $[ \frac 1 2, 1]$. We have to adapt the speed to get the desired reparametrization.
For $n=1$ we get the constant loop $\alpha_{n-1} = \alpha_0$. In that case $\alpha_0 * \omega$ and $\alpha_1$ are not related by a reparametrization. Anyway, this case is irrelevant.
For $n=2$ we have $\alpha_{n-1} * \omega = \alpha_n$, thus $\phi = id$ does the job.
For $n > 2$ we do this:
$\phi$ has to "compress" $[0, \frac{n-1}{n}]$ to $[0, \frac 1 2]$ to deal with the first $n-1$ wrappings and "stretch" $[\frac{n-1}{n},1]$ to $[\frac 1 2,1]$ for the final wrap. This is done by linear (or perhaps better: affine) maps of the form $s \mapsto as + b$. The parameters $a,b$ can easily be determined.

Wow, thanks! I've checked the details and everything works out! What was the thinking process that led you to come up with this solution; i.e. how did you see that we want to map $\left[0,1-\frac{1}{n} \right]$ (linearly; what do you mean by linearly, btw?) onto $\left[0,\frac{1}{2} \right]$ and $\left[1-\frac{1}{n},1 \right]$ linearly onto $\left[\frac{1}{2},1 \right]$?

Well, ok, I think I understand what you mean by linearly now, sorry!

Although I am still interested in how you came up with this solution. That is, how did you see that this is what you wanted to do?

@Ben123 See my update.

Thanks! Hm, I am unsure what you mean by "$[\frac{n-1}{n}, 1]$ is once $(n-1)$-times around $S^1$."

@Ben123 It was a typo (copy and paste ...)
